# documents not being indexed after whoosh StemmingAnalyzer cache change

Tags: python, caching, indexing, whoosh

per whoosh documentation [here](http://whoosh.readthedocs.org/en/latest/batch.html#stemminganalyzer-cache) , giving the StemmingAnalyzer an unbounded cache makes batch indexing faster:

```
writer = myindex.writer()
# Get the analyzer object from a text field
stem_ana = writer.schema["content"].format.analyzer
# Set the cachesize to -1 to indicate unbounded caching
stem_ana.cachesize = -1
# Reset the analyzer to pick up the changed attribute
stem_ana.clear()

# Use the writer to index documents...
```

the only problem is that documents are not being indexed after doing that:
here's my schema:

```
schema = Schema(
                title=TEXT(stored=True, analyzer=StemmingAnalyzer(), field_boost=2.0),
                content=TEXT(stored=True, analyzer=StemmingAnalyzer()),

                owner=NUMERIC(stored=True),
                id=ID(stored=True, unique=True),
                date=DATETIME(stored=True, sortable=True),
                author=TEXT(stored=True),
                system=TEXT(stored=True),
                url=TEXT(stored=True),
                type=TEXT(stored=True),
                service=TEXT(stored=True),
                last_updated=fields.DATETIME)
```

how i index (from xml):

```
docs = xmlObj.findall('document')
for d in docs:
    ...

    writer.update_document(...)

writer.commit()
```

after i changed the stemmer caching, nothing shows up when i do:

```
for doc in ix.reader().iter_docs():
    #doc should be a tuple of (docnum, document)
    print "docnum: {}".format(doc[0])
```

Comment: Please elaborate,  how it isnt indexing? an error shown? 0 documents? You couldnt look them up with a query?

Comment: i edited the question, i am getting 0 documents

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like you are only updating the document when you index.

So if the document isn't there nothing happens, so hence nothing is getting indexed!

try writer.add_document(...)